# Virtual 360º, stitching and presentation software, for use on PHP driven website?

Tags: php, flash, lamp, java-3d, vrml

**EDITED (after 1st answer):**

Can anyone help by pointing to some good references for the creation and presentation of a 3D environment (a real room) on a website.

Ideally it will not involve too much expense or too high a learning curve as this is a one off requirement for a small project.

Answer (score 1):

[VRML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRML), [Java3D](https://java3d.dev.java.net/), or Flash depending on how adventurous you are.

See [Papervision3D](http://www.papervision3d.org/) ([panorama demo](http://www.papervision3d.org/demos/panorama/)) and [360 Degrees of Freedom](http://www.360dof.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Hm... I'm not sure if I understand what exactly do you want to know. But, since I made a similar sites ([panoye](http://www.panoye.com) and [ela](http://www.gallery-ela-porec.com)) I'll try to respond...

There are many different ways to show a panoramic, java applet (ptviewer, very easy but it is java), javascript (bad for spherical images, since it can't deal with equirectangular panoramas distortions) and flash. I use javascript and flashpanoramas flash viewer. With flashpanoramas your php script must create XML files for all panoramas.

For spherical panoramas - I think flash is the way. But then, your panoramas should be cubic, not equirectangular.

Anyway, I'm not sure if there is an quick & easy way...

Answer (score 1):

The [panotools](http://wiki.panotools.org/), and [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) in particular,  suite is quite good if you are looking for a free  tools.  Viewers can also be found [here](http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_Viewers)

Answer (score 0):

Check the stores and gallery i'm operating at [enjoy3d.com](http://enjoy3d.com) .. They use various implementations of Papervision3D. I have developed a toolset and art-pipeline that allows me to create a rich immersive environment in less than a week. And I am currently working on new tech that can handle an 'endless' world with unbounded quantities of content.

I'd also take a look at [Alternativa3D](http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/) if you don't mind paying for licensing